# Was SOIS consulted on Microsoft's new answers page?

Tags: discussion, microsoft

[It looks awfully familiar](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie9beta?page=1&sort=ReplyCount&dir=Desc&tab=all).

[image]

Comment: Well, now we have a shining example of what happens when you try to shoehorn a forum into a Q&A template...

Comment: Answers broke away from the death-grip of the MSDN/Technet forums group about, what, a year ago?  There's a MSFT team behind it that genuinely seems interested in doing a better job, there have been lots of tweaks.  Copying a site that kicked their ass is an obvious strategy.